# Will anyone help me with Getting data from an OPC server into my iPhone Xcode project?

Tags: xcode5, opc

Will anyone help me with Getting data from an OPC server into my iPhone Xcode project?
I have an OPC server and I want to communicate with it to send and receive data from it!
I really have no idea where to start, nevertheless, I need to make this happen!  Anything you could provide would be most helpful!!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. there exists no opc da / ua api library written in objective c. However you can easily find one for .Net thats fully compliant to OPC foundation specifications. You might be able to embed it in iphone using MonoTouch, however that means not using xcode and using c#.